# SAN domain list SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

When creating a SAN certificate you have your base domain that the certificate is for say www.domain.com and then alternate names of say download.domain.com and stream.domain.com. When creating the certificate do you list the base domain name again in the SAN list?

```
eg: 
domain: www.domain.com 
san: download.domain.com,stream.domain.com

vs:
domain: www.domain.com
san: www.domain.com,download.domain.com,stream.domain.com
```

Which one is more correct? which one is better supported?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "Domain" I assume you mean "Subject". As per [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.4), the Subject name is essentially deprecated for HTTP, and the subjectAltName field should be used in all cases where practical:

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity.  Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used.  Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

So yes, you always need to list your subject name in your subjectAltName field. You should do this even if you only have one subject in your certificate.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly the answer I was looking for.